# Function can't be displayed in second canvas within p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

I created two separate canvases with p5.js by creating a new instance (see line 58 in my javascript file). Then I inserted a function called "firstAnimation" that will be displayed in one of the canvases.

Run the code here --> https://editor.p5js.org/MaximilianFreitag/sketches/fP46XAHnP

In line 45 of my javascript file p5.js is telling me that my function "secondAnimation" does not exist. So I can not output another animation in this canvas

In line 49 I can still draw a circle inside the second canvas with sketch.circle(100,100,100).

How can I display my second function in the second canvas so that I have two animations?

[image]

I can only add a simple circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nead to specify where to draw a line. in second function just add  `myp5.line` and just run function secondAnimation() without sketch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).